# static column in oracle10g

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I want to create a table in the following format. The data in first column data is not present in any of the tables. Its a static and constant data.

```
Product        Max        Min
TOY             10         
SHOE            55         25
BAG             40         20
BOOKS           75         55
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Why would you do such a thing? This is the point of a table, to separate data.

Comment: I have been given these constants I want to include these items in the resultset as one column. I tried the below one however it is displaying as a row  "select 'Toys','shoe','Bags','Books' from dual";

Comment: So you don't want it in a table then? You want to create a select statement that has them?

Comment: Yeah, that was the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this give you what you want?

```
select somefields
from sometables
where product in ('TOY', 'SHOE', 'BAG', 'BOOKS')
```